# Matlab - Plot doesn't show

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following function:

```
function [ rad,it ] = bisect( f,a,b,Eps,it,maxit )
X=a:0.1:b;
Y=f(X);
plot(X,Y);
title(sprintf('eps=%d',Eps));
hold on;
format long e;
fa=feval(f,a);
if(abs(fa)<=Eps)
    rad=a;
    return;
end
fb=feval(f,b);
if(abs(fb)<=Eps)
    rad=b;
    return;
end
str=sprintf('a= %d b= %d, fa= %d, fb= %d, it= %d',a,b,fa,fb,it);
disp(str);
if(fa*fb>0)
    error('Unvalid interval');
end
mean=(a+b)/2;
fmean=feval(f,mean);
plot(mean,fmean,'--mo');
if(abs(fmean)<=Eps)
    rad=mean;
    return;
else
    it=it+1;
    if(it==maxit)
        rad=mean;
        warning('Reached maxit but precision is greater than epsilon');
        return;
    end
    if(fa*fmean<0)
        [rad,it]=bisect(f,a,mean,Eps,it,maxit);
    else
        [rad,it]=bisect(f,mean,b,Eps,it,maxit);
    end
end
end
```

The above function is supposed to calculate the root of a function using bisection method and also to plot the function and the intermediate results.

For some reason, it doesn't plot anything now, but was plotting before. I just added `figure();` before every return statement and removed that again. Now it doesn't plot anymore, even if I close Matlab or restart the system.

Comment: do you call `figure` before calling the function?

Comment: This function plots and calculates as expected on my system... `bisect(@(x)x.^3-x-2,1,2,0.000001,1,50)` returns the same as [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+x%5E3-x-2). If you call `figure` within the function, that won't be what you want. It's going to open a new window in each call! You rather want to execute `figure` before calling the function `bisect`. This way the plotting of  `bisect` goes in a new figure as expected.

Comment: Thank you @Matt , the problem why it was not showing is because I have 2 function called bisect.m but in two different folder, i was editing a different one respect to the function i was invoking. Your solution fixed the problem to see separate window for separate functions, i did:
for i=1:7, bisect(f,-3,0,10^-i,0,1000), figure(), end, and i had seven windows as expected. (The param it must be zero, i think you've understood this). thanks!